# Identify iOS peripheral advertising in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth

I work on iOS application with acts as Bluetooth peripheral. I need to implement a searching for my iOS peripheral from non iOS centrals. I’m faced with a problem while my iOS application advertising in background mode. When it is advertising in foreground, my central can read primary service UUID from advertising data, but when it is advertising in background, I can’t see the name or the UUID of peripheral – there is only Apple manufacturer data in advertising packet.

The essence of the problem lies in the fact that my non iOS central can’t determinate – is it advertising my peripheral in background or any other peripheral in background. I have to connect every iOS device with advertising in background, enumerate its services to look for my service UUID.

The documentation says that during background advertising all service UUIDs go to special “overflow” area and only iOS devices can read it specifying service in CBCentralManager’s scanForPeripherialWithServices method. It looks like Apple have an ability to check background advertising packet data for service UUID.

After searching on SO I found some interesting information about service hashed UUID. Background mode advertising packet always contains Apple manufacturer data (14 FF 4c 00 01) and undocumented 128 bit value, where one of these 128 bits equals 1. I tried to change my service UUID several times and found out than this 128 bit value after Apple manufacturer data changes too.

1. I’d like to use this value to filter peripherals around and reduce
   connections to wrong (not mine) peripherals. Can anyone give any
   information how this value depends on service UUID? Is there any
   hash function that is used on specified service UUID in
   scanForPeripherialWithServices method?
2. Can I be sure that the background advertising packet will always be the same for the immutable service UUID which will never change?
3. Is there any other way to send my custom information while
   advertising in background mode? Maybe I can add my data into BLE
   SCAN RESPONSE packet?

Best Regards,
Dezmond

Comment: Hey dezmond. I know it's been a long time, but did you manage to find an answer to the above problem? There is an android library that is supposed to handle backend connections but they stumble actually on your question in the apple forum.
[android library] (https://github.com/yonahforst/discovery-android)
I have made some progress myself, but after some time when an ios device is in the background, I cannot see anymore it's service.. even if I connect to it.

Comment: if you -or anyone- wants more updates on this topic, please join the SO chat-room that I created to discuss this.:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208255/ios-android-ble-topics